# How do you link with another project in .net

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, f#

How do I link with another project in .netcore?

I'm using Linux and VSCode and I want to link to another project that is in another directory on my filesystem, so that when my project compiles it knows to look in that path for the approriate binaries. What should I add to my `*.fsproj`?

Note I'm using F# but the question is language agnostic. The same thing you might do in C# should work.

Comment: In C# and regular VS, you'd right click the project, select Add, the Reference. In the dialog, click the (I think) File Reference tab. Press the Browse button and browse for the assembly you are interested in. Make sure that "copy always" (or something to that effect) is selected. I hope this helps with VS Code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`dotnet add reference` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference) which adds a reference between projects

> The dotnet add reference command provides a convenient option to add
> project references to a project. After running the command, the
>  elements are added to the project file.
>
> ```
> <ItemGroup>
>   <ProjectReference Include="app.csproj" />
>   <ProjectReference Include="..\lib2\lib2.csproj" />
>   <ProjectReference Include="..\lib1\lib1.csproj" />
> </ItemGroup>
> ```

Hth.

---

See also the official Microsoft tutorial [Get started with F# with the .NET Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/get-started/get-started-command-line) which mentions this in a larger context.